# Stack of records theorem for $C^0$ functions?

Tags: real-analysis

Two closely related questions:

1. Is there a stack of records theorem for $C^0$ functions?
2. Is there a $C^0$ function $f$ such that $f^{-1}(0)$ is the Cantor set?

This is related to a paper I am reading where I think the authors may not be looking at some possible pathological cases.

The stack of records theorem (from memory as I don't have Guillemin & Pollack, Diff. Top. here)states that if $p$ is a regular value of $f:X\rightarrow Y$ then the pre-image of $p$, $f^{-1}(p)$, is finite. I am not sure if there is a way of defining regular value for a continuous map.

Comment: I'm not sure about the first question (I don't even know that a stack of records theorem is; care to explain exactly what you mean?), but as for the second question, it's not hard to show that any closed subset of ${\bf R}$ is the zero set of a smooth ($C^\infty$) function.

Comment: Problem 2 is true because any closed subset of real number can be a zero set of some continuous function.

Comment: @tomasz edited the question. not hard to show means we use partitions of the unity right?

Comment: @SergioParreiras 2 follows from the fact that $\Bbb R$ is a normal topological space. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn's_lemma).

Comment: @SergioParreiras: In a way, yes. You can obtain the function in question as the infinite series of bump functions, you just have to make sure that they are decreasing rapidly enough so that all derivatives converge uniformly. I think the same or similar proof should work for any (second-countable smooth) manifold. In much the same way you can prove the same thing for continuous functions on any normal topological space, as Alex suggested (only you don't need to care about derivatives, as there's no such thing).